# RewriteRule - Redirecring specific file types to subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am new to mod_rewrite. I'd like to redirect all htm files in Wordpress root directory to ***docs/filename.htm*** on localhost Wordpress installation meaning ***localhost/a.htm*** should go to ***localhost/docs/a.htm***.  How can I achieve that?  I am using ***/web*** as the base dir of Wordpress.  I tried this without any success.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*?).htm$ docs/$1.htm
```

Also is it possible to redirect only from the root folder? - i.e.  **localhost/a.htm** will redirect to **localhost/docs/a.htm** but the rule should not apply to **localhost/otherdir/a.htm**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ docs/$1.htm [L,NC]
```

Try this